# C-g sometimes doesn't work

Tags: quitting

For the past several weeks, I've experienced an erratic and hard-to-diagnose behavior: the `C-g` key binding sometimes doesn't work. Strangely, this problem doesn't affect alternative bindings of `keyboard-quit`. For example, if I bind `keyboard-quit` to `M-q`, when `C-g` doesn't trigger this command, `M-q` still triggers it.

Because this happens only sometimes and in ways that are hard to predict, bisecting my config file can be very time-consuming. I will do that as a measure of last resort, but I was wondering if anyone has ideas of what might be going on, so I can explore these first. Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the GNU Emacs Manual "51 Quitting and Aborting" ?

Comment: Is `C-g` still bound to `keyboard-quit`?

Comment: If both keys are bound to `keyboard-quit` and only one of them is erratic *under the same circumstances*, then the only explanation I can think of is that your keyboard is flaky. Have you tried another keyboard?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes, I read that section of the manual.

Yes, `C-g` is bound to `keyboard-quit`. But when `C-g` doesn't work, it is not recognized as a key event. For instance, `C-h k C-g` does nothing (whereas when `C-g` does work, `C-h k C-g` shows the `keyboard-quit` binding).  I know this is very weird behavior, but it is what I'm experiencing.

Comment: NickD, I'm using an external keyboard, but I'm almost certain that I also tried my laptop keyboard. However, I will confirm this next time I experience the issue. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Confirmed: it's not an issue with the keyboard.

Comment: Another data point: something equivalent happens with the command `transient-quit-one`, which is by default bound to `C-g` in `transient-base-map`. When this mode is active, e.g. after invoking `magit-status`, `C-g` will often fail to trigger `transient-quit-one`. But if I re-bind it to `M-q`, that key sequence will always work. I don't think I ever experienced such puzzling behavior in Emacs before.

Comment: Instrument `keyboard-quit` with `edebug` and see if Emacs stops there every time you press `C-g` or `M-q`. At least that will tell you whether you get to the command every time. Do that in a throw-away session: you probably don't want to do that in your working Emacs.

Comment: Edebug is triggered only sometimes when I press `C-g` but always when I press `M-q`, in line with the behavior described previously. 

`keyboard-quit` seems like a red herring at this point; I think this issue is instead only related to the `C-g` key sequence, since it also affects `transient-quit-one` and any other command bound to it. E.g. after evaluating `(define-key (current-global-map) (kbd "C-g") #'emacs-version)` the Emacs version is shown only sometimes after pressing `C-g`.